# How to change the font-color of a link-word inside of a <%=link_to ruby tag?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

first of all I'm working on a .html.erb (ruby on rails).

this is the fragment of my code in the file .html.erb:

[image]

And this is the fragment of my code in .scss

[image]

It is working alright for the font-family and the font-size, but it is not changing the color to #FFFFFF (white).

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the link specifically:

```
#sign_up a {
  color: #fff;
}
```